# How to Import GeoJSON data in ArcGIS Javascript maps

Tags: javascript, api, geojson, esri

Can anyone suggest a methodology to import GeoJson data in ArcGIS Javascript maps? I have muiltipoint data in the format recommended by GEoJSON.org (http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id5).

Here is the sample data in my JSON page. (The data has to be accessed using URL)

{ "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [29.626459,-93.034705],[29.626459,-93.034705],[29.626459,-93.034705],[28.786341,-93.045368],[28.786341,-93.045368],[28.786341,-93.045368],[28.786341,-93.045368],[28.786341,-93.045368]]}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this repository. It is a custom esri layer type that loads GeoJSON into a esri graphics layer. Should do the trick for you.

https://github.com/Esri/geojson-layer-js